# Prove that the union of two bounded set in a metric space is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis

Two bounded sets have finite diameter ..but how I prove that union of these sets have finite diameter to show union is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is contained in the ball of center $c_1$ and radius $r_1$

$Y$ is contained in the ball of center $c_2$ and radius $r_2$

let $l$ be the distance $d(c_1,c_2)$ then we have $X\cup Y$ is contained in the ball with center $c_1$ and radius $r_1+d+r_2$ since if $y$ is a point in $Y$ we have

$d(y,c_1)\leq d(y,c_2)+d(c_2,c_1)\leq r_2+l<r_2+l+r_1$